# "Insufficient Privileges" when I enter the Salesforce URL using Chatter Feed Item ID

Tags: chatter, feeditem, insufficient-privileges

when I append the Feed Item ID to the back of the Salesforce URL (sorry for the excessive layman terms as I'm not well versed in programming and the terminologies), the page "Insufficient Privileges" is shown.

e.g.

```
Chatter Feed Item ID = [chatterfeeditemID]  

URL = https://abcd.my.salesforce.com/[chatterfeeditemID]
```

I am trying to view the specific comment from a Chatter report that I've generated. Any ideas or any way of working around this problem? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What is the |d which you're passing to the URL?

Comment: I believe it is the "feed item id"

Answer (score 0):

You can not show a comment without its post. To show the feed and its comment, URL would be like this:-

```
https://{!SalesforceBaseURL}/{!RecordID}?fId={!FeedID}#{!CommentID}
```

`{!RecordID}` can be a `UserID` or the `Record Id` of which this record is associated.